# i want to install NS3 on ubuntu with virtual box

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, compiling, clang

I have started following this tutorial  https://karimmd.github.io/post/tutorial/ns3_installation/
( I'm a beginner and I should precise) and it all went well until I had to write down this line of code :

```
sudo apt install g++ pkg-config sqlite3 qt5-default mercurial ipython3 openmpi-bin openmpi-common openmpi-doc libopenmpi-dev autoconf cvs bzr unrar gdb valgrind uncrustify doxygen graphviz imagemagick python3-sphinx dia tcpdump libxml2 libxml2-dev cmake libc6-dev libc6-dev-i386 libclang-6.0-dev llvm-6.0-dev automake"
```

ubuntu says ( it's translated from French)
-"qt5-default" has no installable version
-cannot find package libclang-6.0-dev
-Unable to locate package matching the regular expression "libclang-6.0-dev".
-Unable to locate package libclang-6.0-dev
-unable to locate package corresponding to the regular expression 'llvm-6.0-dev

it happened after I wrote the code below

Comment: it says qt5 default package is missing

Comment: the same goes for libxml2

Comment: and libclang-6.0-dev and llvm-6.0-dev

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't just `sudo apt install ns3`?

Comment: The install instructions at the link are from 2021, and are specifically for Ubuntu 20.04. It seems worthless, since the `ns3` package has been in the Ubuntu repositories for at least a decade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: Undo EVERYTHING that you did so far. If you installed it, then remove it. Return your system to as close to stock condition as possible. This is the hard part. You MUST be thorough.

- Any wrong-version packages left on your system will prevent Step 2 from working. If you do not understand how package management works, consider backing up your data and reinstalling Ubuntu.

Step 2: On a stock Ubuntu system,

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ns3
```

Comment: oh thanks the good news is im using oracle virtual box so it wont be that difficult to reinstall